# OpenLayers only keeps the first drawn feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I would like to save all my drawings on a vector layer stored in a PostgreSQL database and shared by GeoServer for a web mapping application.

I wonder why this piece of OpenLayers/JS code (*as found here : http://codepen.io/barbalex/pen/fBpyb*) doesn't work. Only the first drawn feature is kept.

Why?

Is it a bug with OpenLayers?